# How do I implement this swipe navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I wanted to add the swipe nav bar which is as shown in the GIF, to my app.

[image: Settings>Apps]

**EDIT:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

I tried the following code to implement this nav bar, basically it has a title strip and navigation bar, But now.. How do I use different layouts for different navigation swipes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check Android navigation example with source code at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I particularly want this kind of nav bar, I dont know how to do this. I have tried sherlock nav action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` from the support libraries.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a ViewPager, Fragments and PagerTitleStrip

You can read about that here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip

I strongly recommend for you to learn how to use and deal with Fragments in an App, if you aren't using them already. It's needed in a ViewPager.

Comment: I don't have 50rep to comment yet. So, I'm commenting here.
— — — — —
You must create fragments. At first, fragments in a ViewPager can be treated as Activities, create classes extending support.Fragment. Override the OnCreateView method in a Fragment's class and supply a view for it.
Then you can set them in the ViewPager.

Comment: great, but if possible can you edit my code and assist me. :)

Comment: If you need multiple layouts, then you must create multiple fragments.
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using